# Нужно проверить, нет ли лишних символов в строке (php)

Tags: php

Помогите составить регулярное выражение на php для preg_match. Нужно проверить, нет ли лишних символов в строке. Допустимые символы:

```
0-9a-zа-яёA-ZА-ЯЁ"'’-+,.()/ и пробел
```

Забирание спасибо!

Comment: Думаю можно перевести строку в массив, и сделать массив с доступными символами, и сравнивать каждый символ строки со всеми разрешенными символами массива.

Comment: @Fr3nD зачем? Не проще сделать регулярное выражение?

Comment: Через массив будет долго, как разработка кода, так и его обработка. Для этого и придумали регулярные выражения. Вот правда я в них не силен...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Шаблон `~[^\s\d\pL"\'’,.()/+-]+~u`. С PHP будет так:

```
$str = 'Строка для теста';

if (preg_match('~[^\s\d\pL"\'’,.()/+-]+~u', $str)) {
    echo 'Недопустимые символы!';
}
```

Здесь:

1. `[^...]` - символьный класс с отрицанием
2. `\s` - символьный класс пробельных символов
3. `\d` - символьный класс чисел
4. `\pL` - символьный класс литералов *(буквы лат. и русс. [последние - при указании модификатора "u"])*

Все остальные символы означают сами себя, а так как они находятся внутри символьного класса, то круглые скобки экранированию не подлежат.

Answer (score 0):

Да у вас собственно в вопросе уже почти готовое регулярное выражение написано:

```perl
/^[\da-zа-яё"’\x27-\x29\x2B-\x2F\x20]+$/iu
```

где:

- `^` — токен, обозначающий начало строки,
- `[]` — соответствие одному символу из списка:

  - `\d` — эквивалентно `[0-9]`, т.е. любая цифра,
  - `a-z` — диапазон символов от `a` до `z`,
  - `а-я` — диапазон символов от `а` до `я`,
  - `ё` — соответствует букве `ё`, она не входит в диапазон `а-я`, поэтому её нужно указывать отдельно,
  - `"` — соответствует символу `"` (U+0022) буквально,
  - `’` — соответствует символу `’` (U+2019) буквально,
  - `\x27-\x29` — диапазон символов от `'` (U+0027) до `)` (U+0029), включающий в себя `'`, `(`, `)`,
  - `\x2B-\x2F` — диапазон символов от `+` (U+002B) до `/` (U+002F), включающий в себя `+`, `,`, `-`, `.`, `/`,
  - `\x20` — соответствует пробелу (U+0020).
- `+` — токен, обозначающий, что символы могут встречаться один и более раз,
- `$` — токен, обозначающий конец строки.

Модификаторы:

- `i` — без учёта регистра,
- `u` — unicode трактовка.